# Shortest way to replace date in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss' format with 'yyyy-mm-05 hh:ii:ss'?

Tags: php, date, time

What is the shortest way to replace date in `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss'` format with `'yyyy-mm-05 hh:ii:ss'`?

I need to change the date days, not to subtract several days from the date.

Thank you.

Comment: `preg_replace('/-\d{2} /', '-05 ', $str)`? Seems like using a date add/substract approach or `mktime()` etc would be better, but if your string format is static then that would work, and it's probably the *shortest* (i.e. least code) way of doing it. It's not hugely fault tolerant though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = '2012-06-08 11:15:00';
echo date('Y-m-05 H:i:s', strtotime($date)); // 2012-06-05 23:15:00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go with:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-06-08 12:00:00');
$dt->setDate($dt->format('Y'), $dt->format('m'), 5);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Maybe not the shortest, but it's a solid approach

Comment: +1 for using the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: +1 for the *best* way of doing it, which is what the OP should really have asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) that will be shortest way

Agree with @DaveRandom. It's shortest way

```
preg_replace('/-\d{2} /','-05 ',$str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way (not the best one) to do it is using the substr_replace() function.

```
$input = '2012-06-08 11:15:00';
$output = substr_replace($input, '05', 8, 2);
echo($output);
```